# Azure App Service Container HealthCheck - small

Tags: docker, containers, azure-appservice, docker-healthcheck

I have a Azure App Service Container failing on the healthcheck.
My docker is a very light Alpine, but I do have netcat

The app service fails because port 80 is not responding on the container. The container is not a web server.

My Dockerfile: (there is no service to return on port 80 in this container )

```
EXPOSE 80
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

What can I put in the dockerfile to be the healthcheck ?
How do I write the Dockerfile ?